# Cannot get data from Google Analytics (401 Unauthorized)

Tags: java, google-analytics, oauth-2.0

I try to implement basic data feed example  and all I get is just:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized.

But when I use http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html
It works fine with my Google Analytics account.

It seems I've done everything according to OAuth2 instructions: created client id and client secret, enabled Analytcs API.

Also I've tried to get my profiles and accounts with Analytics Management API but I get the same error. What do I do wrong?

Here is my code (of course I run this code with actual CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and TABLE_ID):

```
public class AnalyticsTest {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "MY_CLIENT_ID";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET";
    private static final String REDIRECT_URL = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "test";
    private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics";
// TRIED AS WELL private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds";
    private static final String TABLE_ID = "MY_TABLE_ID";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            NetHttpTransport netHttpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            // Generate the URL to send the user to grant access.
            String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URL, SCOPE).build();

            // Direct user to the authorization URI.
            System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
            System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

            // Get authorization code from user.
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
            String authorizationCode = null;
            authorizationCode = in.readLine();

            // Use the authorization code to get an access token and a refresh
            // token.
            AccessTokenResponse response = null;
            try {
                    response = new GoogleAccessTokenRequest.GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, authorizationCode, REDIRECT_URL).execute();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Use the access and refresh tokens to get a new
            // GoogleAccessProtectedResource.
            GoogleAccessProtectedResource googleAccessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(response.accessToken, netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, response.refreshToken);

            Analytics analytics = Analytics
                            .builder(netHttpTransport, jacksonFactory)
                            .setHttpRequestInitializer(googleAccessProtectedResource)
                            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
            //System.out.println(analytics.management().accounts().list().execute());

            Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get(TABLE_ID, // "ga:" + Profile
                            // Id.
                            "2011-09-01", // Start date.
                            "2011-12-23", // End date.
                            "ga:visits"); // Metrics.

            try {
                    GaData gaData = apiQuery.execute();
                    // Success. Do something cool!

            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                    // Catch API specific errors.
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Catch general parsing errors.
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
>   {
>    "code" : 401,
>    "errors" : [ {
>      "domain" : "global",
>      "location" : "Authorization",
>      "locationType" : "header",
>      "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
>      "reason" : "authError"
>    } ],
>    "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
>   }
>     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:138)
>     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClient.execute(GoogleClient.java:123)
>     at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpRequest.executeUnparsed(JsonHttpRequest.java:67)
>     at com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics$Data$Ga$Get.execute(Analytics.java:1335)
>     at voc.AnalyticsTest.main(AnalyticsTest.java:76)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your scope from this:

```
private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics";
```

to this:

```
private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
```